# How can the chlorophyll concentration of plants be measured?

Tags: organic-chemistry, home-experiment

Is there a way to measure the [chlorophyll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll#Spectrophotometry) content of plants (from e.g. leaves) with basic chemistry equipment (at home)?

Answer (score 1):

To measure the total chlorophyll from leaves, probably not, since you need access to methyl isobutyl ether or pyridine.

But you can separate the different pigments in the leaf. From [The Naked Scientist](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/HTML/content/kitchenscience/exp/chlorophyll-chromatography/): Cut a rectangle 1 cm wide and long enough to stand up in a small jar from a coffee filter. Place your leaf over the top of the strip and roll the coin across the strip about 2 cm from the bottom. Now add a little nail varnish remover to the bottom of your jar, half a cm is plenty. Suspend your strip of paper so the bottom end is sticking a few mm into the acetone. you can hold it up by folding the top end of the strip over forming a hook which will rest over the lip of the jar. Wait a few minutes, with any luck you should see an interesting effect. Try the experiment with a strongly colored leaf like a purple one.